# How many ways there are to post 10 different letters in 10 distinguishable post boxes if at least one post box should be empty?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know how to count ways to arrange $10$ different letters in 10 boxes($10^{10}$) but I can't figure out how to count ways based on the condition.

Comment: Subtract those that have only one letter in each post box...

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You have to put `$` signs around the MathJax for the formatting commands to take effect.

Comment: **Hint:** Calculate the probability of the complementary event. And then subtract the probability of this complementary event from $1$.

$$P(\textrm{" at least one post box is empty"})=1-P(\textrm{"every post box contains at least one letter"})$$ Ignore that I´ve used probabilities.

Comment: @callculus But probability is not asked in the question.

Comment: @Ak19 Do you agree the complementary event is "every post box contains at least one letter", or do I miss something?

Comment: How many ways are there to put the 10 letters in, period (ie, without worrying about leaving a box empty)? How many ways are there to put the letters in, so that every box has a letter?